# Addition of times

Tags: c#

I have a problem with adding times. Actually time addition is occur after AM to PM.

I will give you an example.

```
Arrival Time | Waiting Time | Departure Time | Travel Time
10:30 PM     | 60           | 11:30 PM       | 0
11:30 PM     | 5            | 11:35 PM       | 5
11:40 PM     | 10           | 11:50 PM       | 10
```

The addition goes by these formula:

> Departure Time = Arrival Time + Waiting Time
>
> Next Arrival Time = Departure Time + Travel Time

So the Problem is after addition of 11:50 PM + 10 (min) it shows us
1.00:20:00 but it should be 12:00 PM

Comment: What have you done? Show us the code that you written ...

Comment: I guess there's something wrong in your code, which we cannot see

Comment: MR. David Heffernan there are no Wrong in COde

Comment: Mr. David Heffernan Whole code is properly run

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TimeSpan` like this

```
//Get the time part with TimeOfDay
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 10, 3, 11, 50, 00); //03/10/2015 11:50:00
var time = dt.TimeOfDay; //11:50:00
//Or get a TimeSpan directly
time = new TimeSpan(11, 50, 00); //11:50:00
//Add the new TimeSpan
var nextTime = time.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 00)); //12:00:00
```

Basically, you can create a instance of `TimeSpan` by specifying hours, minutes, seconds like this

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(14, 50, 00); //14:50:00
```

In your problem, you should be using `DateTime` variables to hold all your timings, and display just the time part (maybe). Otherwise, when the time goes to next date, it'll be confusing and error prone.

Answer (score 2):

When working with times, it is important to understand how times are represented in .NET.

- A `DateTime` is a fixed point in time; a specific time of the day on a specific date. It doesn't make sense to add two `DateTime` values to eachother.
- A `TimeSpan` is a duration. They can be added and subtracted from eachother. It's also possible to add a `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime` to produce a new `DateTime`.

In your case, you should represent the Arrival and departure times as a `DateTime` while you should use `TimeSpan` for the waiting and travel times.

You would still get the day-wrapping though, because if you add 10 minutes to a `DateTime` with value 1900-01-01 23:50 you get 1900-01-02 0:00 which is in the next day. If you are using `DateTime` to represent just time, you probably have an implicit date of 1900-01-01. To cut away the date, use `DateTime.TimeOfDay`.